Why is the file path different in production compared to development when using Expo?
When I ran my Expo server locally on my iPhone, saving the captured reference of a view worked perfectly and saved the image to the correct path. However, after building the app for production, I’m unable to access logs, and when I try to save an image, it results in a black screen image. I suspect that either the file path is different in production or the capture process isn’t working correctly, but I’m not sure why this is happening.
I’ve confirmed that the user has all the necessary permissions, so I don’t think it’s a permissions issue. I tried different ways to display logs to troubleshoot, but I couldn’t see them properly. I was expecting the image to save correctly, just as it did in the development environment, but instead, I’m getting a black screen image.
Code:
handleOk func:
 const handleOK = async (signature) => {
        const { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();

        if (status === 'granted') {
            // Extract the filename from the saveImageUri
            const filename = saveImageUri.split('/').pop(); // Extract filename from URI

            // Construct the cameraPath using the extracted filename
            const cameraPath = FileSystem.cacheDirectory + "Camera/" + filename;

            try {
                // Save the image to the cache directory
                // await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
                //     cameraPath,
                //     signature.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", ""),
                //     { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 }
                // );

                const index = capturedPhotos.findIndex(photo => photo.uri === saveImageUri);
                // Get the new URI for the signature image using handleCapture
                const newSignatureUri = await handleCapture(capturedPhotos[index].width, capturedPhotos[index].height);

                if (index !== -1) {
                    // Create a copy of the capturedPhotos array
                    const updatedPhotos = [...capturedPhotos];

                    // Update the URI of the image at the found index
                    updatedPhotos[index].uri = newSignatureUri.uri;
                    updatedPhotos[index].width = newSignatureUri.width;
                    updatedPhotos[index].height = newSignatureUri.height;

                    // Set the updated array as the new state
                    setCapturedPhotos(updatedPhotos);


                    setSaveImageUri('')
                    setDrawMode(false);
                    setIndexImage(index);


                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Permission to access camera roll was denied');
        }
    };

Handle Capture func:
const handleCapture = async (capWidth, capHeight) => {
        logMessage("Capture started");
        if (!scrollViewRef.current) {
            logMessage('ScrollView reference not found');
            Alert.alert('Error', 'ScrollView reference not found');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const uri = await captureRef(scrollViewRef);
            logMessage(`Captured URI: ${uri}`);

            const directory = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'photos/';
            const filename = `Kamera_${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}_${new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:/g, '')}.jpg`;

            const newUri = directory + filename;
            logMessage(`Directory: ${directory}`);
            logMessage(`filename: ${filename}`);
            logMessage(`New URI: ${newUri}`);

            const dirInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(directory);
            if (!dirInfo.exists) {
                await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(directory, { intermediates: true });
                logMessage(`Creating photos folder didnt exist`);
            }

            await FileSystem.copyAsync({
                from: uri,
                to: newUri,
            });

            logMessage('Capture succeeded');
            return { uri: newUri, width: capWidth, height: capHeight };
        } catch (error) {
            logMessage(`Capture failed: ${error.message}`);
            console.error('Capture failed:', error);
            return error;
        }
    };

